# WSO2 BAM Documentation

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I am trying to set up WSO2 BAM and API Manager integration by following the documentation at [Publishing API Runtime Statistics](https://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics).

There is a line in the documentation to drop Hive table

> add the following line at the beginning of the Hive script and rerun.
>   drop table ;

It is not clear where to add this line and what exact table to drop. Can someone provide more information on this one?

BAM is throwing following exception and I am assuming it is related to above changes required

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
[2014-04-09 09:08:00,122] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver} -  FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTa
sk
[2014-04-09 09:08:00,123] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl} -  Error while executing Hive script.
Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log into BAM. Select Main -> Analytics -> Add. This will bring up an editor to provide your script. You can give drop table statements here and then click execute. You don't need to save this before hitting execute.

Comment: Thanks Amila. Do you know which table needs to be dropped? It says drop table <hive_cassandra_table_name>

Comment: This document specified which tables should be deleted https://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics. See Changing the statistics database section